# tomcat 7 taglib inconsistent specification version

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

I have included the taglib as -

```
<%@ taglib prefix="wf" uri="http://www.wrox.com/begjsp/el-functions-taglib" %>
```

and the web.xml is

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
       // some description and name


   <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>
       http://www.wrox.com/begjsp/el-functions-taglib
    </taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>
       /WEB-INF/jsp/function-taglib.tld
    </taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

However, deploying this application gives following error log (catalina.out)

> INFO: Deploying web application archive
>   /home/eanautg/2bkp/jsp/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ch05.war
>
> Sep 8, 2013 5:57:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester
>   startElement SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: taglib definition not consistent
>   with specification version
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibLocationRule.begin(WebRuleSet.java:1274)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:504)
>   ...
>
> Sep 8, 2013 5:57:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig
>   parseWebXml SEVERE: Occurred at line 13 column 16 Sep 8, 2013 5:57:39
>   PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart SEVERE:
>   Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)

I have tried to change schema and version number to 3.0 but in vain --

```
schema = "...web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">`
```

I read on another thread that taglib should not be defined in web.xml. Then where should it be as per new spec ? Am I missing something ? please let me know.
Thanks,
Stacy.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this helps but I came across this article about Tomcat 7 taglib declarations when trying to find an issue with a blackboard plugin.

http://help.blackboard.com/en-us/Learn/9.1_SP_14/Administrator/010_Release_Notes/025_SP14_Release_Notes/Performance_and_Scalability/Tomcat_7

In Tomcat 7, in your web.xml file your tag libs should be wrapped in a < jsp-config > element.